# Balsamiq - Making the area of the iphone scrollable or bigger to fit more content

Tags: balsamiq

Is it possible to make the iphone screen bigger or scrollable so that one can fit more content that is scrollable?

Right now, the items in the phone screen don't fit and so I would like to fit more content by allowing for a scrollable area.

I know there is a list view, but this can only fit data. I want to draw icons and what not on my area.

Thanks!

Comment: Balsamiq sucks big time. Just saying. I don't know why anyone would promote this shit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simulate swiping, do this:

1) Create your content that needs to be swiped and place the iPhone with the transparent screen (look in properties) on top of the content. The content needs to be the same width of the screen, but maybe 25% taller.

2) Create two views:

One with the top of the content flush with the top of the iPhone screen, with a scroll bar on the far right and an xl icon of a finger pointing up at the bottom. The extra content will hide behind the bottom of the phone.

A copy of the first, but move the content upwards a bit so that the content at the top is now behind the top of the phone. Move the value of the scrollbar down a bit, and move the finger icon up so that it is pointing at the same part of the content it was pointing at before.

3) Add a link to the two finger icons so that they point to the other view. This should help to simulate swiping.

I've included some examples below.

[image: begin swipe img]

[image: end swipe img]

Comment: Good idea. This "scrolling" is actually a link to multiple view, which show the content according to scrollbar position. The important part of this trick is on the "Hand Icon", which is a link to other view. In this case if there would be more than 2 pages, we can put "up" and "down" icon.